# Issue trying to align image under table

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" bgcolor="#C5C5C5">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:10px 0">  
                        <table align="left" width="49%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" align="left" class="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0 10px">
                                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0"><a href="#"><img width="230" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1428628618/image01_et7dqm.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="border-radius: 4px; width: 230px; display: block;" class="deviceWidth" /></a></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table align="right" width="49%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 13px; color: #959595; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: top; padding:20px 0 20px 15px">

                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" style="padding:0 10px 15px 0">
                                                <img  src="http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/free_template_1/6.jpg" alt="" border="0" align="left" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="middle" style="padding:0 10px 10px 0"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #363636; font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif ">Two column - text right</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>    

                                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0;padding:5px">
                                        SOME TEXT ABOUT SOMETHING YET TO BE CONFIRMED
                                        <br/><br/>

                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                                                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><!-- End 2 Column Images  - text left -->               
        <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                  <a href="#"><img width="20" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1428628617/triangle_C5C5C5_ks8sg2.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="border-radius: 0px; width: 20px; display: block;" class="deviceWidth" />
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:10px 0">  
                        <table align="left" width="49%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" align="left" class="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0 10px">
                                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0"><a href="#"><img width="230" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1428628616/image1.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="border-radius: 4px; width: 230px; display: block;" class="deviceWidth" /></a></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table align="right" width="49%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 13px; color: #959595; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: top; padding:20px 0 20px 15px">

                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" style="padding:0 10px 15px 0">
                                                <img  src="http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/free_template_1/6.jpg" alt="" border="0" align="left" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="middle" style="padding:0 10px 10px 0"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #363636; font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif ">Two column - text right</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>    

                                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0;padding:5px">
                                        SOME TEXT YET TO BE CONFRMED
                                        <br/><br/>

                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                                                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

which renders as follows

[image]

As you can see at the bottom I have a triangle which I'm trying to position so it overflows on to the next box, unfortunately I can not for the life of me get it to sit correctly, i.e the white space between the dark shade and lighter shade of gray to dis-appear can someone give me a hand please the end result is to look like this :

[image]

Comment: Would you please present more codes after that triangle?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour added the next gray box.

Comment: Just a suggestion: keep your style separated from HTML. This will help a lot to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is recommended not to use tables for formatting page sections. In this case you can set the Parent of triangle as a relative positioned element with height of 0px and position triangle as absolute element. So:

```
<div class="deviceWidth" style="width:580px;position:relative;height:0;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
        <img width="20" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1428628617/triangle_C5C5C5_ks8sg2.jpg" alt=""  style="border:0;position:absolute;top:0;right:20px;border-radius: 0px; width: 20px;" class="deviceWidth">
        </div>
```

also please note that :

1. remove the display:block from image
2. set border:0 inside styles not as a separate attribute
3. I have added **margin-right:auto** and **margin-left:-auto** to align div in center of screen